# How to substitute SQL date(field_date) by Spark filter?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code that uses `sql`:

```
val yesterdayDate = "2018-03-13"
df.createOrReplaceTempView("myTable")
val result = spark.sql("select * from myTable where date(field_date) = '" + yesterdayDate)
```

The values of `field_date` have the following format `2018-02-13 23:55:11.382928`.

I want to get the same result using `filter` or `where` of Spark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following *sql query* should work for you

```
val yesterdayDate = "2018-03-13"
df.createOrReplaceTempView("myTable")
val result = spark.sql(s"select * from myTable where date(field_date) == '${yesterdayDate}'")

result.show(false)
```

**If you don't want to use sql query** then you can *use sql api* as below

```
val yesterdayDate = "2018-03-13"
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.select("*").where(date_format(col("field_date"), "yyyy-MM-dd") === yesterdayDate).show(false)
```

Comment: My question says that I want to avoid using Spark sql API. Sorry, if it was unclear.

Comment: I want to use `filter` or `where` without `spark.sql`.

Comment: @Markus, Updated my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to say, in spark sql API?

If yes you can do

```
import spark.implicits._

val yesterdayDate = "2018-03-13"
val df = spark.read // read the source

val result = df.select("*").where($"field_date" === s"$yesterdayDate")
```

I had to edit here instead in comments.

```
df.select("*").where(functions.date_format($"field_date".cast(DateType), "yyyy-MM-dd") === s"$yesterdayDate")
```

Comment: Yes, I refer to Spark sql API. If you do `where($"field_date" === s"$yesterdayDate")`, then dates are in different formats, no?

Comment: Yes they are different types but you can cast one of the values. For exemple df.select("*").where(functions.date_format($"field_date".cast(DateType), "yyyy-MM-dd") === s"$yesterdayDate")

Comment: So, the answer does not reflect it.